VS Code: How to debug a Python method in debug console
I have started a Python script in VS Code's debugger and have hit a breakpoint. I can examine the state in Debug Console.
Now I would like to call a method with parameters from within the Debug Console and follow (debug) it's execution.

I've set a breakpoint in the method I call, but it is ignored: Debug Console immediately returns the result from the method, instead of interrupting at the breakpoint. Seems like debugging in Debug Console is not supported.
Any idea how to debug from Debug Console?

It'd help to make a toy example so that we can try it for ourselves. See related tips at [mre]

Breakpoints usually are for regular execution of your main script, rather than triggered by other methods. The debug console is for evaluation of the current state of the code

FWIW, I just tried doing the same sort of thing with pdb and it also skipped the breakpoint in a function if I used p to run the function.

I cannot explain why it is this way, but code you execute in the debugging console does not trigger breakpoints. And exceptions thrown on the debugging console do not crash your main script.
That's just how the debugging console works.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can try this:

Set breakpoints within the method.
Start debugging (run button dropdown or F5, according to your keybindings).
Use step controls (F10, F11, Shift+F11, according to your keybindings) to navigate.
Inspect method variables in the Variables pane. 


My problem is that when I‘m in Debug Console I cannot debug a method that I call from within the Debug Console.

The code information you provided is too little, I give a possible answer：
Maybe the location of your breakpoint contains a method belonging to another package. You could add "justMyCode": false to your launch.json.

It‘s not an issue with justMyCode.
